# Issue with Bookmarked (and normal) chats with Skype4Py

Tags: python, skype4py

As the title suggests, I cannot seem to find some chats when using Skype4Py.

I've run this code:

```
def get_bookmarked_chats():
for b in skype.BookmarkedChats:
    print b.Topic
```

which should loop through all my bookmarked/favorite chats and print the topic. However, I have about 8 bookmarked chats, and this prints 9, only 5 of which are currently bookmarked, and ignores the other 3, and prints  4 chats that are no longer bookmarked. I have rerun

```
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.FriendlyName = 'Extract_chat_history'
skype.Attach()
print("Successfully connected to Skype account '" + Skype4Py.Skype.User(skype).Handle + "'.")
```

with no issues, and other code to retrieve new messages for the chats (that are recognized) seems to work perfectly fine. I have the newest skype installed (Version 7.0.59.102 according to Help -> About Skype), and I have clicked the star to bookmark/unbookmark chats. I have also tried looping through `skype.Chats`to try and find the chat I want to add bookmark with Skype4Py, but am unable to find the chat there either to do so.

If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Skype stopped using P2P for Skype group chats mid-to-late 2014 and now defaults to cloud-based groups which the Skype API does not support.

To confirm that the groups that aren't appearing are cloud-based, try this chat command in those groups:

```
/get name
```

If the result starts with

```
19:
```

then it is indeed a cloud-based group.

The only way to get those cloud-based groups to appear in your application is to re-create them as P2P-based groups.

Issue the following command in any Skype chat in order to create a new P2P-based group.

```
/createmoderatedchat
```

Comment: None of my skype conversations start with 19: though?

There are some that require the JOINING_ENABLED option on before I can /get uri as well, are those the cloud-based groups?

Comment: Does `/get name` return "19:" on any of the groups that are not appearing? I would like to believe that those are cloud-based but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, on the ones I was unable to find in the Skype4Py API, `/get name` returns 19:***

Comment: The issue is definitely being caused by the lack of cloud-based group support in the Skype API. Your only option is to re-create the group as a P2P-based group.